# Android Listview Scrolling inserts duplicate records

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, android-listview, android-adapter

I had created a Custom Listview that has EditText box. When I change the text in the EditText, I am updating the field to database. It is working fine.

The Problem I am facing is when I scroll the list, records are added to the database (duplicating records)... I feel this issue can be solved by removing EditText focus during the ListView Scrolling, I don't know how to do it. Or else if some can give better idea means it will be helpful.

This is my ListAdapter Code

```
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class ZoneListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Zone> {

protected static final String LOG_TAG = ZoneListAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
private PfDatabase db;

private List<Zone> items;
private int layoutResourceId;
private Context context;
int companyid;
public ZoneListAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, List<Zone> items, int companyid) {
    super(context, layoutResourceId, items);
    this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
    this.context = context;
    this.items = items;
    this.companyid=companyid;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ZoneHolder holder = null;

    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
    row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    holder = new ZoneHolder();
    holder.zoneList = items.get(position);


    holder.Label = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLable);
    holder.iCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
    holder.dbid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dbid);

    setZoneLabelTextChangeListener(holder);


    row.setTag(holder);

    setupItem(holder);
    return row;
}

private void setupItem(ZoneHolder holder) {
    holder.Label.setText(holder.zoneList.getLabel());
    holder.iCount.setText(holder.zoneList.getCounter()+"");
}

public static class ZoneHolder {
    Zone zoneList;
    EditText Label;
    TextView iCount;
    TextView dbid;
}

private void setZoneLabelTextChangeListener(final ZoneHolder holder) {
    holder.Label.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            //holder.zoneList.setLabel(s.toString());
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) { }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            holder.zoneList.setLabel(s.toString());
            db = new ProfireDatabase(context);
            String strDBID = holder.dbid.getText().toString();
            Log.d("DBID",strDBID);
            if(strDBID.equals("TextView")){ //Insert New Record
                db.insertZone(companyid, s.toString());
                Cursor getId = db.myQuery("SELECT _id from zone order by _id DESC limit 1");
                int CompanyID = getId.getInt(0);
                holder.dbid.setText(""+CompanyID);
            } else { //Update Record
                int iRowId = Integer.parseInt(strDBID);
                Log.d("ROW ID",iRowId+"");
                db.updatezone(iRowId, s.toString());
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}

In My Activity I am loading the ListView like this

```
if (strAction != null && strAction.equals("new")){
        //For New Records
        istrID = Integer.parseInt(strID);
        ZoneListView.setAdapter(zadapter);
    } else {
        //Loading the records from database for the company id
        ZoneListView.setAdapter(zadapter);
            istrID = Integer.parseInt(strID);
            Cursor getZone = db.myQuery("Select * from zone where companyid="+istrID);
            if (getZone != null) {
                while(getZone.moveToNext()) {
                    zadapter.insert(new Zone(getZone.getString(1),getZone.getInt(0)), 0);
            }
                getZone.close();
    }
}
```

The problem I am facing is, when I load the records from database, due to EditText focus moves, due to that the records are getting inserted in Database (even during the listview scroll also).

I would like to know how to avoid the duplicate records getting inserted in database

Answer (score 0):

As you now that getView() will be called everytime whenever user is scrolling the list up and down. 
I actually don't know the exact requirement but you should set the TextWatcher listener on click of Editbox. What it will do is, it will not call your TextWatcher evertime userscroll up and down.
When you add TextWatcher on onClickListener of editbox you can remove the focus of editbox once you finished the editing.

Answer (score 0):

You problem is not about the `EditText` getting focused. It's about your `TextWatcher` getting called every time `getView` is called.

An easy way to fix this is to remove the `TextWatcher` before `getView` changes the text, and add it back later, which means you need to keep a reference to your `TextWatcher`

BTW, another problem in your code is that you are using the holder wrong.

Edit your code as below.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;
    ZoneHolder holder = null;
    if(row == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);
        holder = new ZoneHolder();
        holder.Label = (EditText)row.findViewById(R.id.txtLable);
        holder.iCount = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.FirstText);
        holder.dbid = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.dbid);

        row.setTag(holder);
    }else{
        holder = (ZoneHolder) row.getTag();
    }

    holder.zoneList = items.get(position);

    if(holder.watcher != null){
         holder.Label.removeTextChangedListener(holder.watcher);
    }

    setupItem(holder);

    holder.Label.addTextChangedListener(/* Your watcher goes here */);

    return row;
}

private void setupItem(ZoneHolder holder) {
    holder.Label.setText(holder.zoneList.getLabel());
    holder.iCount.setText(holder.zoneList.getCounter()+"");
}

public static class ZoneHolder {
    Zone zoneList;
    EditText Label;
    TextView iCount;
    TextView dbid;
    TextWatcher watcher;
}
```